# Include bootstrap in react component in codepen

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, codepen

How do I add bootstrap classes to my jsx in codepen? I was trying to add `container-fluid`, `row`, and `col-*` to my divs in jsx but they're not working, anyone knows how?

Comment: Have you tried loading in the [Bootstrap stylesheet from a CDN](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css)?

Comment: Yea, it works for the html but it doesn't affect the React component

Comment: Are you writing `className` instead of `class` for your JSX? I.e. not `<div class="container-fluid"> ... </div>`, but instead `<div className="container-fluid"> ... </div>`.

Comment: O yea!!! forgot about that, thanks I'll try it and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install bootstrap :

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Then add the following import statement to index.js file

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

instead of writing `<div class="container-fluid"></div>` you write 
`<div className="container-fluid"></div>`